# Create single file on clonezilla?

Tags: clone, clonezilla

Is it possible to create a single RAW image file using clonezilla and then mount it?

I ask this because I have been recommended this instead of ddrescue, but ddrescue creates a raw .img that allows me to mount it.

Is there any way?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly. I guess it refers to the mount point. It may be that you mount it in /mnt/tempimg

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla had dd for creating raw image just start image creation as expert and use the priority selection *dd -> other* instead *partclone -> disk image -> dd* 
to create a single image on the section request you the maximum size set it to 0;
in Linux you can mount safely any raw image also created with dd just using mount.
in windows you can use this tools: https://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

Comment: Many do not recommend the use of dd because it does not show the progress bar. Do you know if Clonezilla does it?

Comment: Don't know it, normally I do not use, but I can suppose it does; anyway it is possible to monitor dd progress, read here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for everything. I see that there are multiple uses for pv. How do you work with any utility?

Comment: @MarianoM i did not get your last question clear, you mean how I work with pv or the question mean PV could work with any utility? in the first case, I do not use, in case of dd I add flag status=progress, in the second case you have to read the documentation or search if some body already ask it or post another question.